# View onclick method affected by its parent onclick method

Tags: android, onclick

Welcome guys,
I have relative layout and two imageViews inside.
When I set the onClick method of the relative layout and set different methods for onclick methods for the two imageViews.
The relative layout method cancels the 2 imageViews methods why??

```
    package com.example.test2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* Remove title bar from transparent activity */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*Define Views*/
        final ImageView keyboardIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardIcon);
        final ImageView micIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.micIcon);
        final RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        /** Icons on click events */
        micIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mic icon",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        keyboardIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "keyboard icon",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        final Animation moveMicIconRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_right);
        final Animation moveKeyIconLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_left);

        micIcon.startAnimation(moveMicIconRight);
        keyboardIcon.startAnimation(moveKeyIconLeft);

        /** Relative layout on click event*/
        RL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

EDIT:
I made some changes

```
package com.example.test2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* Remove title bar from transparent activity */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /* Define Views */
        final ImageView keyboardIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardIcon);
        final ImageView micIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.micIcon);
        final RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        RL.setOnClickListener(this);
        keyboardIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        micIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

        final Animation moveMicIconRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_right);
        final Animation moveKeyIconLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.move_left);

        micIcon.startAnimation(moveMicIconRight);
        keyboardIcon.startAnimation(moveKeyIconLeft);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.activity_main:
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        case R.id.keyboardIcon:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "keyboard icon",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.micIcon:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mic icon",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and my xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/keyboard_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/micIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/mic_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Set OnClickListener for the layout before the other 2.

Comment: @Aashir Sry didn't work

Comment: @amitsingh See the edited question 
thnx

Comment: @blackbelt as shown above :)

Comment: I noticed something 
When I click on the original place of the view before animation onclick method works great.

Comment: I guess, the problem is due to the animation, check once without applying animation.

Comment: I searched and I found that 
the animation doesn't really move the view so I have to use 
realtiveLayout Params 
and set margins but margins doesn't work with relative layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from animation because it moved just the imageView and not its real location.
I used ObjectAnimator instead :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the descendantFocusability of your relative layout. It seems to be acting before its descendants, or even blocking them. To fix this you will need to add the xml attribute

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

to your relative layout in xml.